# I want to set This delimiter String in insert values as a column

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I have this delimiter String '1|1|3|5|Alpesh'.

i want set this value in INSERT INTO VALUES (1,1,3,5,Alpesh) like this.

how do i do that in MYSQL with trigger.

Comment: Why do you want a trigger?

Comment: because i want fire this query when trigger is hit

Comment: MYSQL does not have a split string function. You will have to write one yourself or find one.